# Redirect (301) one route to another from routing.yml in Symfony2

Tags: redirect, routes, symfony

I know this is probably trivial, but I couldn't find anything on the web or in the Symfony2 reference.

How do I redirect one route to another from routing.yml (with 301 status code)?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
SomeRoute:
    pattern: /someroute
    defaults: { _controller: SomeBundle:Controller:action }

AnotherRoute:
    pattern: /anotherroute
    defaults: { _redirect: {route: SomeRoute, status: 301} }
```

I could create a controller, but it seems overkill, since I don't have any parameters (and it would be overkill even so, if they are to be passed as they are).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
SomeRoute:
    pattern: /someroute
    defaults:
        _controller: SomeBundle:Controller:action

AnotherRoute:
    pattern: /anotherroute
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: SomeRoute
        permanent: true # this is for 301
        page: 5 # you can pass additional attributes
```

Comment: what if the route has parameters?

Comment: @crudolf, added an example of using an attribute.

Comment: Official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html

Comment: How do you pass a parameter from the original pattern to the redirected route? for example, to redirect ```pattern: /user/{username}/posts``` to ```pattern: /user/{username}```?