# Routing in Symfony2: optional parameter en four urls for one route

Tags: php, url, symfony, routes

In my Symfony2 application I would like to make four urls possible with one route:

1. a-lot-of-other-stuff/report/-20 **(negative number)**
2. a-lot-of-other-stuff/report/40 **(positive number)**
3. a-lot-of-other-stuff/report/ **(no number)**
4. a-lot-of-other-stuff/report **(no number and no / )**

My route currently looks like this:

```
report:
    pattern:  /report/{days}
    defaults: { _controller: "AppReportBundle:Report:dayReport", days = null }
```

The action is defined as:

```
public function dayReportAction($days = null)
{
    // my code here
}
```

This currently makes url 1 and 2 working but in the case of url 3 and 4, I get an error

> Route not found

How can I make the parameter "days" optional?
And if the parameter is not provided, how can I allow the `/` to be omitted as well?

Comment: It's very strange. Because 4th route should work. I often use optional parameters but I use Annotation Route definition. I shouldn't define defaults in annotation if I define default value in function signature. Maybe you need to omit one of the defaults declaration (for example in your routing.yml) or try to use numeric (or string/bool) value instead of null. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Your route config should be: `defaults: { _controller: "AppReportBundle:Report:dayReport", days: null }`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a way to do this

<kbd>**routing.yml**</kbd>

```
report:
    pattern: /report/{days}
    defaults: { _controller: "AppReportBundle:Report:dayReport", days: null }
    requirements:
        days: -?\d+

report_reroute:
    pattern: /report/
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: report
        permanent: true
```

Since requirements is a regexp pattern it lets you have a negative number.

The reroute section forces the route `/report/` to redirect on `/report`
You can read about this on: <kbd>[**Cookbok Entry**](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html)</kbd> - <kbd>[**Elnur's Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529850/1607098)</kbd>

With such behaviour, you would have:

```
Route       | Action                 | Parameters
------------|------------------------|-------------
/report     | dayReportAction        | $days = null
/report/    | 301 to /report         |
/report/60  | dayReportAction        | $days = 60
/report/-4  | dayReportAction        | $days = -4
/report/foo | 404                    |
```

Comment: Is it possible to supress other parts in route in the order is referred, for instance, using previous routes: 'a-lot-of-other-stuff/report/40', where '/report/' could be optional so the ending would be: 'a-lot-of-other-stuff/40', asuming that I have default behaviors included in my routes? How could we achieve this?

Comment: @Félix You would want to create a new route to the same controller action. If you're interested in a full answer, you should create a new question.

Comment: I've created a new question here, please visit it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766700/intermediate-route-optional-parameters-in-symfony-2