# Symfony - Auto redirect

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I'd like to create some service that would be responsible for auto-redirecting some routes to secure version of the URL. For example:

```
http://domain.com/checkout -> https://secure.domain.com/checkout
http://domain.com/about // route not marked as secure, no redirection
```

I know I can partially achieve that with schema:

```
secure:
    path:     /secure
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:secure }
    schemes:  [https]
```

However I also need to change hosts. Should I hook up to some kernel events or something?

Comment: Is there anything wrong using a [standard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8529850/1607098) [redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17060748/1607098) ?

Comment: Why not use `.htaccess`

Comment: @ThomasK, that would be a valid option, however we don't want to maintain two tools (router and htaccess) to achieve something that simple. It's just a consistency matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up with is:

1) I've set a custom option in the routing (`https`):

```
acme_dynamic:
    pattern:  /
    options:
        https: true
    defaults:
        _controller: acmeCommonBundle:Default:dynamic
```

2) I've created a listener for `kernel.response` event:

```
namespace acme\CommonBundle\EventListener;

use acme\CommonBundle\Controller\HttpsController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class HttpsControllerListener
{
    /**
     * Base HTTPS Url
     * @var string
     */
    private $httpsUrl;

    /**
     * Request
     * @var [type]
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * [$router description]
     * @var [type]
     */
    private $router;

    public function __construct($httpsUrl, $request, $router)
    {
        $this->httpsUrl = $httpsUrl;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $routeCollection = $this->router->getRouteCollection();
        $route = $routeCollection->get($this->request->get('_route'));

        if ($route and $route->getOption('https') === true and $this->request->server->get('HTTPS')) {
            $response = $event->getResponse();
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->httpsUrl . $this->request->server->get('REQUEST_URI')));
        }
    }
}
```

3) I've registered it to the mentioned event:

```
acme.https_controller_listener:
    class: acme\CommonBundle\EventListener\HttpsControllerListener
    arguments: [%baseurl.https%, @request, @router]
    scope: request
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

Basically it intercepts response, checks if current route has `https` option set in the routing configuration, if so, checks if it's on a secure connection - if not, redirects to secure domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use listener to `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents::REQUEST` event, documentation how to create similar listener here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html. This way you can add any logic you need. You get `GetResponseEvent` as an argument, so you can just return from method or set redirect response to that event.