# Symfony2 redirect 301 not changing the url

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I have a simple redirectt in my routing.yml file:

```
products_in_categories:
    path: /{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: MpShopBundle:Category:show }

redirect_category:
    path: /112-redirect-this
    defaults:
        _controller: MpShopBundle:Category:show
        route: products_in_categories
        slug: to-this
        permanent: true
```

So when I go to `localhost/web/app_dev.php/112-redirect-this` it should do a 301 redirect and change the url... It load the pages successfully, but the url is not changed. It shows:

`localhost/web/app_dev.php/112-redirect-this` when it should show:
`localhost/web/app_dev.php/to-this`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect (301) one route to another from routing.yml in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529038/redirect-301-one-route-to-another-from-routing-yml-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Symfony documentation your redirecting route should point to the `FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect` action:

```
redirect_category:
    path: /112-redirect-this
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: products_in_categories
        slug: to-this
        permanent: true
```

It's described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_in_config.html#redirecting-using-a-route

Comment: Oh my god and I thought you need to write your controller location there... thanks!!